# Change a Flash AS3 context menu that is already personalized -- can't find it to change?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, contextmenu

Is there any way to change a context menu that already has been personalized.  I have an small application that I purchased to learn with and also to save some time.

When I right click the context menu appears with the other person's information in it.  I want to change that information if it is possible to do so.  I tried

```
var my_menu:ContextMenu = new ContextMenu();
my_menu.hideBuiltInItems();
contextMenu = my_menu;
```

and added my info but the menu will not change from the person I got the app from.  Is this considered unethical or illegal?  I put so much work into this, I don't want the person to get credit for it.

How can I change the context info?
Thanks in advance for any help you might offer.
Annie

Comment: also I looked through the movie and used the movie explorer to show only actionscript and could not find where the context menu was personalized.  Could it be hidden somewhere?

Thanks
Annie

Answer (score 0):

I found the customized text for the context menu and it was on a page with a stop on line 1 and then after about 70 lines they inserted the information.  Since only stop(); is seen on line 1 with nothing following, it appeared this is the only actionscript for the frame.  Very clever!